# Angular CSS class issue on Google Chrome Version 99+

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome, angular-material

I get a weird CSS issue after upgrading chrome to v99+
In the first image as seen, the CSS is applied to the `<li>` according to active route link.
[image]

When the user navigates to the other route, the CSS is removed from the HTML tags as seen in the chrome dev tools, but the font color still remains green even though there are no styles there.
[image]
The font color only reverts to normal **White** only when I hover my mouse cursor over that first `<li>`, as seen in the image below.

[image]
Is this an issue with google engine rendering or my Angular app?

Has someone experienced such behavior before, grateful to read your insights?

Comment: I would say its a redraw issue on chromes side. the active class is gone from the dom so Angular did its job.

Comment: I take it the styling is correct on Firefox/Edge?

Comment: @Drenai, yep, working fine on incognito as well.